# The Text Value isn't Changing in Roblox Studio, Lua

Tags: lua, roblox

I am struggling with my Delivery System for my new game, Opix Islands, and I believe that it is this script causing problems. I think that the Value is changing correctly, but I'm not 100% sure. I believe the problem to be the changing of the text. I have made sure it is told to change before the gui is moved. Thanks for any help.

Also, I have researched on the Roblox Developer Forum to Check it isn't the Random Function and I don't believe it is. I also haven't seen any errors but the onscreen text is definitely not changing.

```
script.Parent.ClickDetector.MouseClick:Connect(function(plr)

    script.Parent.Parent.Script.BoxPresent.Value = false
    local value = math.random(1,6)
    wait()
    local text = script.BoxUi.TextLabel.Text
    if value == 0 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: Delivery Depot, Opix"
    elseif value == 1 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 1 Market Street, Opix"
    elseif value == 2 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 2 Market Street, Opix"
    elseif value == 3 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 3 Market Street, Opix"
    elseif value == 4 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 4 Market Street, Opix"
    elseif value == 5 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 5 Market Street, Opix"
    elseif value == 6 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 6 Market Street, Opix"
    end
    print ("Destination Setting Complete.")
    script.BoxUi.Value.Value = value    
    local gui = script.BoxUi:Clone()
    gui.Parent = plr.PlayerGui
    local box = script.Parent
    box.Parent = plr.Backpack

    



end)
```

Comment: so the value isn't changing but you believe it is changing but you are not sure? what? either it changes or it does not. which one is it?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your response. The Value does change correctly with the random function so there must be an issue setting the text. Thanks.
@Piglet

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 local text = script.BoxUi.TextLabel.Text
```

creates a copy of `script.BoxUi.TextLabel.Text`, not a reference to it! References are only created for objects as Tables, functions, threads and (full) userdata values.

changing text as in

```
 text = "Deliver the Package to: Delivery Depot, Opix"
```

has no effect on `script.BoxUi.TextLabel.Text` as you are only changing the value that once contained a copy of it.

What you actually want to do is:

```
script.BoxUi.TextLabel.Text = "Deliver the Package to: Delivery Depot, Opix"
```

or

```
local text = "Deliver the Package to: Delivery Depot, Opix"
script.BoxUi.TextLabel.Text = text
```

And instead of this:

```
local value = math.random(1,6)
local text
if value == 0 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: Delivery Depot, Opix"
elseif value == 1 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 1 Market Street, Opix"
elseif value == 2 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 2 Market Street, Opix"
elseif value == 3 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 3 Market Street, Opix"
elseif value == 4 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 4 Market Street, Opix"
elseif value == 5 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 5 Market Street, Opix"
elseif value == 6 then
    text = "Deliver the Package to: 6 Market Street, Opix"
end
```

You could simply write

```
local text = "Deliver the Package to: " .. value .. " Market Street, Opix"
```

or

```
local text = string.format("Deliver the Package to: %d Market Street, Opix", value)
```

There is no need for all those `if/elsif` statements

Also note that `math.random(1,6)` won't ever yield 0 so your 0-case is not needed.